# drake visualizer not displaying anything

Tags: drake

OS: Ubuntu 16.04, NVIDIA Driver

I followed the drake installation procedure as described in [drake website](https://drake.mit.edu/docker.html).(I have also installed nvidia driver)After installation, as per the instructions when I run:

```
$ xhost +local:root; nvidia-docker run -i --rm -e DISPLAY -e QT_X11_NO_MITSHM=1 -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix --privileged -t drake; xhost -local:root
```

I am getting the following error:(simulation is not being displayed, but the build is successful)

```
non-network local connections being added to access control list
+ [[ 0 -eq 0 ]]
+ bazel build //tools:drake_visualizer //examples/acrobot:run_passive
Starting local Bazel server and connecting to it...
INFO: Analysed 2 targets (95 packages loaded, 18023 targets configured).
INFO: Found 2 targets...
INFO: Elapsed time: 89.206s, Critical Path: 1.58s
INFO: 0 processes.
INFO: Build completed successfully, 1 total action
+ sleep 2
+ ./bazel-bin/tools/drake_visualizer
+ bazel run //examples/acrobot:run_passive
INFO: Analysed target //examples/acrobot:run_passive (0 packages loaded, 0 targets configured).
INFO: Found 1 target...
Target //examples/acrobot:run_passive up-to-date:
  bazel-bin/examples/acrobot/run_passive
INFO: Elapsed time: 1.031s, Critical Path: 0.01s
INFO: 0 processes.
INFO: Build completed successfully, 1 total action
INFO: Build completed successfully, 1 total action
process 297: D-Bus library appears to be incorrectly set up; failed to read machine uuid: UUID file '/etc/machine-id' should contain a hex string of length 32, not length 0, with no other text
See the manual page for dbus-uuidgen to correct this issue.
libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
Could not initialize OpenGL for RasterGLSurface, reverting to RasterSurface.
Could not initialize OpenGL for RasterGLSurface, reverting to RasterSurface.
Could not initialize OpenGL for RasterGLSurface, reverting to RasterSurface.
Could not initialize GLX
./setup/ubuntu/docker/entrypoint.sh: line 15:   297 Aborted                 (core dumped) ./bazel-bin/tools/drake_visualizer
non-network local connections being removed from access control list
```

Answer (score 0):

We are in the process of updating the instructions to use nvidia-docker 2.0. Please check the drake repo again later this week for an update. In meantime, you may wish to try the open-source driver instructions on the same page.